# check exist post value in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

How can I check exist post value in python flask?

I am a PHP programmer, and it will be like this in PHP.

```
function profile_update()
{
    if($this->input->post('photo))
    {
        echo 'photo is exist';
    }else{
        echo 'photo is not exist';
    }
}
```

I would like to make like this in python flask, but it makes an error.

```
@app.route('/apis/settings/profile_update_submit', methods=['POST'])
def settings_profile_update_submit_test():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    phone = request.form['phone']
    photo = request.file['photo']

if 'photo' in request.files:
    return 'photo exists'
else:
    return 'photo does not exist'
```

This keep showing 'photo does not exist' message even though I put a file in the form.

Comment: Is your indentation correct for those `if` statements? They are not part of the `settings_profile_update_submit_test()` function as posted.

Comment: *but it makes an error*: Then *include that error* (the full traceback) in your question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. It just show internal error on the browser. that's why I couldn't put error message over here.

Comment: But your log file (in the console) will show the error. If you set `DEBUG = True` in your configuration you'll see it in your browser as well.

Comment: I've rolled back the change as it changes your question; but your method would still show an error as you didn't change the first `request.file` line. Does my version not work either?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah..     if 'photo' in request.files:
        return 'photo exists'
    else:
        return 'photo does not exist'

Comment: This keep showing 'photo does not exit' message..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Test for the file *first*:

```
@app.route('/apis/settings/profile_update_submit', methods=['POST'])
def settings_profile_update_submit_test():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    phone = request.form['phone']

    if 'photo' in request.files:
        return 'photo exists'
    else
        return 'photo does not exist'
```

Trying to access a non-existing key will raise a `KeyError` exception otherwise.

You can also use `.get(key, default)` to return a default (`None` if you omit a more specific default):

```
photo = request.files.get('photo')
if photo is not None:
    return 'photo exists'
else
    return 'photo does not exist'
```

Comment: I tried with your codes, but it makes error like this. AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'file'

Comment: Isn't your `.get()` logic wrong. `if photo is None: return 'photo does not exist'`?

Comment: Please look at the question again. It shows 'photo does not exist' message on the browser even though I put a file in the form.

Comment: @Jake - please check Martijns updated code, just a missing `not`